# .htaccess: Deny if folder contains 'public' subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I think it should be an easy thing to do, but I need some help with this...

I have a sandbox site where I have multiple installations of applications that would normally run independently. For convenience, they are all on a common site, let's say http://website.com.

For example, I have:
http://website.com/site1
http://website.com/site2

As folder structure, site1 and site2 look like this:

```
site1/
    - .env
    - otherfiles.txt
    - public/
        - index.htm
```

The 'public' folder is the actual webroot if the app was published.

I would like to write a rule that says, very simply: "If this folder contains a subfolder named 'public', deny access". To do what you would normally achieve simply putting those files outside of the webroot.

This should make both .env and otherfiles.txt denied but leave everything under 'public' accessible.

I hope it makes sense.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I think you’re shooting yourself in the foot here with that “convenience” ... I would always recommend to keep dev environment setups as close to production as possible, that will cause the least problems/surprises. If you nevertheless still want this, I think you’ll need to involve mod_rewrite (a RewriteCond can “check” whether or not a folder exists; there isn’t much else available that can do that), […]

Comment: […] and if so, set an environment variable via the following RewriteRule, so that you can switch authentication on/off based on that variable. (Whether those two things, rewriting and authentication, even happen in the correct order for this to work, you’d have to test though.)